# Allow browser to hit a .cshtml file and display the content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, razor, iis-7

I know this is a very odd request but to cut a long story short a developer have the wrong URL that has now been printed on material.  The url was a .cshtml file which obviously is not allowed to be hit through IIS.

I need to allow this particular cshtml or all of them to be rendered as plain html in the browser.

Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Just for clarification, do you mean you want the source of the cshtml file to be displayed or rather the server to parse and render it like you would expect if they used the route correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not NOT the best solution, but it is the one I know of the top of my head.

Go to your Global.asax file. From there go inside of or create the Application_AcquireRequestState function as so:

`void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e) { }`

Inside the above function check to see if the path matches your .cshtml file. If so, do `Server.Transfer` to a regular aspx page.

You might also have to go into IIS settings and enable cshtml to be served.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IIS mod_rewrite extension with a regex for all cshtml files, or just this particular one.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

OR, in the IIS manager use the MIME Types configuration and add .cshtml as type text/html

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Application_BeginRequest event to check the extension of the file and apply some logic then redirect them.

In Global.asax.cs file:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.Url.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".cshtml"))
        {
            //Your logic to apply
            Response.RedirectToRoutePermanent("Default"); 
        }
    }
```