# ASP.NET MVC Startup 404 error The Resource cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Sorry, I re-downloaded the project from TFS and the startup page is loading now. I guess the config file was not correct.

I got a new project and trying to startup the MVC project with Visual Studio.
When the specified startup page is loaded, I get the following error

> Server Error in '/' Application
>   The resource cannot be found
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
>   Requested URL: /Views/Cases/MyPage.cshtml

Comment: Do not access the cshtml file. Access the action method which returns the cshtml. `yourbaseUrl/Cases/MyPage` ?

Comment: Are you staying not to set the MyPage.cshtml as the Start Page? The Action are in the Controller .cs file. How do I set that or route to that? Thanks.

Comment: Get yourself familiarized with mvc routing.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18237168/allow-browser-to-hit-a-cshtml-file-and-display-the-content

Comment: Unlike ASPX, CSHTML files can't be accessed directly - it needs controller action method that has `return View()` to load it (i.e. `class CasesController` and `ActionResult MyPage()`, then use URL format as Shyju said.